# Integer array in Python

Tags: python

How I can define array of integer numbers in Python code

Say if this code is ok. or no

```
pos = [int]

len = 99

for i in range (0,99):
    pos[i]=7
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your goal some. It's not too too common to fill up a list like this.

Comment: You do not need to declare types in Python. `[int]` defines a list of one element, which is the `int` type (as a first-class object itself).

Answer (score 11):

Why not just:

```
pos = [7] * 99
```

This is the most pythonic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

```
import array

pos = array.array('l', 7 * [99])
```

The [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array) module of Python's standard library is the only way to make an *array* that comes with Python (the third-party module `numpy` offers other ways, but needs do be downloaded and installed separately) -- what your Q is doing, as well as every answer so far, is building a `list`, **not** an `array`.

In particular, there is no constraint that the `pos` list built in your Q and the several As contains just integers -- while, with the snippet I give, you *do* get that constraint (32-bit signed integers in this case, to be precise), which rigidly limits you but also saves a bunch of memory (an array of integers should take about one fifth the amount of memory that a list filled with integers will take, unless there's a lot of perennial duplication in the lists' items).

BTW, if you say `array` when you mean `list` (just in case `list` *is* what you meant), you're sure to cause a lot of confusion -- saying what you mean, and meaning what you say, helps a *lot* in clear communication, unsurprisingly!-)

Comment: `0 <= Probability("OP means array.array, not list" | code_in_the_question) < epsilon`

Answer (score 4):

you do not declare the type of variables in python, so no `pos=[int]`
all you have to do:

```
pos=[]
for i in range(99):
    pos.append(7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
pos = [7] * 99
print pos #will print the whole array [7, 7, .... 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to declare the array, all you have to do in python is:

```
pos = []
```

If you want to fill the array with 99 7's:

```
pos = [7] * 99
```

If you want to fill the array based on a pattern:

```
pos = [i for i in range(99)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
pos = [7 for _ in xrange(0,99)]
```

in Python 2 or:

```
pos = [7 for _ in range(0,99)]
```

in Python 3.  These are [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and are easy to extend for more complex work.

Also:

```
pos = [int]
```

doesn't make much sense.  You're creating a list with the only element being the type int.

Comment: `xrange(0, 99)==xrange(99)`: the first element is zero, by default!